# Angular add class to active element

Tags: css, angularjs, json, menu

How i can add active class to menu with angular with this case

html code

```
<div class="categories" ng-controller="CategoryController">    
  <ul class="menu">     
    <li ng-repeat="category in categories">
      <a ng-click="sendCategory(category)">{{category.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>    
</div>
```

js code

```
myApp.factory('Categories', ['$http',      
    function ($http) {      
        return {       
            get: function (callback) {      
                $http.get('data/categories.json').success(function (data) {      
                    callback(data);       
                })       
            }       
        }       
    }       
]);
```

Comment: add a property to `category`

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax:

```
<ul class="menu" ng-class="{classname: variableFromScope}">
```

Set this variable to true or false (to activate or disactivate your `classname` class) in your controller where it needed:

```
$scope.variableFromScope = true;
```

Comment: It giving me error

`Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.6/$parse/syntax?p0=classname&p1=is[object Object]nexpected%C%expecting%%5B%A%D&p2=3&p3=%B%Bclassname%A&p4=classname%A`

Comment: I forgot the quotes in ng-class attribute. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I've added to my category controller no change
`myApp.controller('CategoryController', function($scope, $route, $location, $http, Categories){      
  
  Categories.get(function(response){       
    $scope.categories = response;
  });
  
  $scope.sendCategory = function(category) {
    $location.path(category.name);
  };
  $scope.variableFromScope = true;
 
}) `

Answer (score 0):

here is solution

html code
`<ul class="menu">

    <li ng-repeat="category in categories"><a ng-click="sendCategory(category)" ng-class="{ active: activePath=='/{{category.name}}' }">{{category.name}}</a>

    </li>

</ul>`

js code

`
myApp.controller('CategoryController', function ($scope, $route, $location, $http, Categories){

```
Categories.get(function (response) {
    $scope.categories = response;
});

$scope.sendCategory = function (category) {
    $location.path(category.name);
};
$scope.activePath = null;
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function () {
    $scope.activePath = $location.path();
    console.log($location.path());
});
```

})`